# create transaction to stored procedures calls under c#

Tags: c#, .net, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am using stored procedures in sql server.
I have several stored procedures calls written in c#. I want to wrap them inside transaction:

```
//Begin Transaction here
sp1Call();
sp2Call();
sp3Call();
//Commit here
//Rollback if failed
```

is there any way to do it?

Update:
I am using the enterprise library. example to sp1Call():

```
public static void sp1Call(string itemName)
    {
        DbCommand command = db.GetStoredProcCommand("dbo.sp1_insertItem");
        db.AddInParameter(command, "@item_name", DbType.String, itemName);
        db.ExecuteNonQuery(command);
    }
```

Comment: How do you call your procedures? What client api do you use?

Comment: I am using Enterprise Library. Please see Updates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to check out [`SqlTransaction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction.aspx).

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Microsoft.Practices libraries, but quickly browsing the documentation, it looks like you'll need `TransactionScope` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5w5se33) instead.

Comment: I can't find a way to do this with the Enterprise Library framework.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you just need to wrap your calls to `sp1Call()`, `sp2Call()`, etc. in a `using(var tran = new TransactionScope())` block.

Comment: Oh, and call `tran.Complete()` at the end of the block.

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick search comes up with [DBTransaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbtransaction.aspx):

```
   using (DbConnection connection = db.CreateConnection())
   {
     connection.Open();
     DbTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
     try
     {
        DbCommand command = db.GetStoredProcCommand("dbo.sp1_insertItem");
        db.AddInParameter(command, "@item_name", DbType.String, itemName);
        db.ExecuteNonQuery(command, transaction);
        transaction.Commit();                   
     }
     catch
     {
       //Roll back the transaction.
       transaction.Rollback();
     }  
   }
```

Comment: I am using the enterprise library. I have more then 100 stored procedures. I can't change each of them to your format.

Comment: why would you have to change the stored proc themselves for this?

Comment: I would have to change the calls to the stored procedures.

Comment: So I am telling you I can't afford that.

Comment: the only other idea is something more AOP oriented like transaction scopes, which allows you to include multiple methods w/o changing the method's code itself. There's an article here: http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2007/01/27/transactionscopedataaccessapplicationblock.aspx